# How can I Fullscreen (F11) Chrome without hiding webpage tabs?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I want to use chrome in fullscreen.

When I go fullscreen (F11), the windows taskbar at the bottom AND the page tabs at the top get hidden.

I like it when the windows taskbar is hidden, but don't want my tabs at the top to be hidden.

How can I only hide the taskbar, but keep the tabs visible?

Comment: The taskbar can be set to auto-hide when the mouse is elsewhere, maybe that’s good enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F11</kbd> is to make the current page fullscreen, so the tabs will disappear. Hiding the taskbar is a Windows issue.

You can make the taskbar autohide.  It (they) will be hidden until you hover where they would normally appear.

- Right Click on Taskbar
- Click on **Taskbar Settings**
- Turn On **Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop/tablet mode**

I also **Lock the taskbar**.